# claves con htaccess en un servidor con cakephp

Tags: html, .htaccess, cakephp, .htpasswd

tengo una pagina en

```
midominio.com.co/descargas/mibd.html
```

esta pagina esta alojada en `webroot/descargas/mibd.html`

estoy creando un htaccess ahí, esta es su ubicacion

```
webroot/descargas/.htaccess
```

y creo que tengo algún error al llamarlo o crearlo porque no me funciona, a continuación les muestro lo que me sale:

.htpasswd

```
Andres:$apr1$jX8xN1hg$VJJSDz6GR5qtQVkV40EQA0
```

.htaccess

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"

AuthType Basic

AuthUserFile /var/www/midominio.com.co/descargas/.htpasswd

AuthGroupFile /dev/null

require valid-user
```

la idea es que cuando entre a la pagina `midominio.com.co/descargas/mibd.html` me pida una clave para poder ver el contenido

[image: Error]

por cuestiones de seguridad no puedo dar la verdadera url de "midominio" y "mibd.html" se ve su nombre real en la imagen del error.

Answer (score 1):

fijate si en el .conf del virtualhost (para averiguar cual es `$ sudo apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`) por lo general es `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

hay una seccion para esa carpeta y si en esa sección está habilitado el .htaccess

```
<Directory /var/www/midominio.com.co/descargas/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`AllowOverride All` <-

Opcionalmente  podes definir la auth directamente en la misma sección del .conf

Edit 2: acabo de ver que es un hosting compartido, segun la página del hosting tenes cPanel, deberás buscar ahi la opción de proteger carpetas.
Suele estar bajo la categoría Seguridad (Security) 
Si no lo tienes habilitado deberás contactar al soporte del hosting

Edit 3: en algunos casos deberas editar el .htaccess generado para que incluya la línea:

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
```

Comment: Esto seria en el htaccess que esta en la cabeza?

Comment: en el virtualhost, ahi te agregué como averiguar cual está cargando

Comment: ahi te agregue info para intentar setear el htacces via cPanel (seguramente haya algun tipo de restricción) y una configuracion extra por si globalmente han redefinido el error 401